# JNDI lookup for connection pooling

Tags: mysql, jndi, connection-pooling

I am trying to get pool of connections using jndi lookup but have a following error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

My context xml placed in web/WEB-INF folder near web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" crossContext="true" reloadable="true" path="patient/account">
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/pharmacy"
            author="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="32"
            maxIdle="8"
            maxWait="10000"
            username="root"
            password="23810198vas"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pharmacy"  />
</Context>
```

```
Context envCtx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/pharmacy");
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: For Tomcat , context.xml should be under **META-INF** and  **META-INF** folder should be at the same level as **WEB-INF** folder.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tomcat , context.xml should be under META-INF and META-INF folder should be at the same level as WEB-INF folder.